# Limit a number to a range (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-theory, hindley-milner

I am exposing a function which takes two parameters, one is a minimum bound and the other is a maximum bound. How can I ensure, using types, that for example the minimum bound is not greater than the maximum bound?

I want to avoid creating a smart constructor and returning a Maybe because it would make the whole usage more cumbersome.

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but one approach that sometimes works is to change your *interpretation* of your type. For example, instead of

```
data Range = {lo :: Integer, hi :: Integer}
```

you could use

```
data Range = {lo :: Integer, size :: Natural}
```

This way, there's no way to represent an invalid range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I like how changing the interpretation keeps things simple.

Answer (score 10):

This solution uses dependent types (and might be too heavyweight, check if *dfeuer*'s answer is enough for your needs).

The solution makes use of the `GHC.TypeLits` module from *base*, and also of the [*typelits-witnesses*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses-0.2.3.0) package.

Here is a difference function that takes two integer arguments (known statically) and complains at compile-time when the first number is greater than the second:

```
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language TypeOperators #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.TypeLits.Compare
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Proxy
import Control.Applicative

difference :: forall n m. (KnownNat n,KnownNat m,n <= m) 
           => Proxy n 
           -> Proxy m 
           -> Integer
difference pn pm = natVal pm - natVal pn
```

We can check it from GHCi:

```
ghci> import Data.Proxy
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
ghci> :set -XDataKinds
ghci> difference (Proxy @2) (Proxy @7)
5
ghci> difference (Proxy @7) (Proxy @2)
** TYPE ERROR **
```

But what if we want to use the function with values determined at run time? Say, values that we read from console, or from a file?

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   case (,) <$> someNatVal 2 <*> someNatVal 7 of
       Just (SomeNat proxyn,SomeNat proxym) ->
            case isLE proxyn proxym of
                Just Refl -> print $ difference proxyn proxym 
                Nothing   -> error "first number not less or equal"
       Nothing ->     
            error "could not bring KnownNat into scope"
```

In this case, we use functions like [`someNatVal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:someNatVal) and [`isLE`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses-0.2.3.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits-Compare.html#v:isLE). These functions might fail with `Nothing`. If they succeed, however, they return a value that "witnesses" some constraint. And by pattern-matching on the witness, we bring that constraint into scope (this works because the witness is a GADT).

In the example, the `Just (SomeNat proxyn,SomeNat proxym)` pattern match brings `KnownNat` constraints for the two arguments into scope. And the `Just Refl` pattern match brings the [`n <= m`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:-60--61-) constraint into scope. Only then we can call our `difference` function.

So, in a way, we have shifted all the busywork of ensuring that the arguments satisfy the required preconditions out of the function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, cool stuff :). But I think it is a bit too much and I find dfeuer's answer to be much more simple and satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is dependent types. There is a nice tutorial on it in
https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell

Although I don't know how friendly it will be. Do note that dependent typing was improved in GHC 8.0 but I have no experience in that area. I would make sure you're comfortable using template Haskell if you don't want it to be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You needn't invoke the `Maybe` type to take advantage of 'smart constructors'. If you like, you may accept constructors of either form `(min,max)` or `(max,min)` and still create a `data` type which correctly interprets which is  which.

For instance, you could make a little module:

```
module RangeMinMax (
               Range,
               makeRange
              )
where

data Range = Range (Integer,Integer)
  deriving Show
makeRange a b = Range (min a b, max a b)
```

And now when you create a `Range` using `makeRange`, the 2-tuple will automatically be arranged so it's in the form `(min,max)`. Note that the constructor for `Range` is not exported, so the user of the module is unable to create an invalid `Range`-- you just need to make sure that you create valid ones in the this module.